# jQuery clearInterval issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a script to check if a file exists every 5s on onclick event. When it exists, I notify the client and reset the counter. First file check everything works fine, but when I check another file (click on another link with other data-file), it checks again both files and first file check is looping forever until I refresh the page. I tried everything I could think of, nothing worked. Please help!

```
var intervalCheck;

function isFileExists(file) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'HEAD',
        url: '/apps/'+file,
        success: function() {
            alert('found '+file);
            clearInterval(intervalCheck);
        },  
        error: function() {
        }
    });
}

$('#dialog').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var file = $(e.relatedTarget).data('file');
    $("a#checkfile").click(function() { intervalCheck = setInterval(function() { isFileExists(file); },5000); });
});
```

Comment: I think you should unbind the click event handler when modal is closed. There maybe now multiple modal "instances" active at same time.

Comment: @Hardy, `Event-delegation` would be a better way...

Comment: initialize `intervalCheck` to null for the first time. So every time it will start with null.

Comment: Also note, `intervalCheck` should be local variable...You can pass it as argument to `isFileExists` function..so that every time you `click` it will create new instance of `intervalCheck`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must bind click event to only a#checkfile in clicked #dialog. Otherwise it will bind event to all a#checkfile elements. So when you open dialog for second time there will be 2 events on the a#checkfile link.

```
$(this).find('a#checkfile')
```

**UPDATE**
If there is one dialog contains multiple links, you can use jquery's `one` function for one-time events.

```
$('a#checkfile').one('click', function(){});
```